# Error in fetching json data from web url usin ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem in accessing server side value into my jQuery function. I gave my localhost path (NewsRecord.php) as the AJAX URL (it is working) but if I give server path it is not working... I don't know what is the problem -- the server URL prints the JSON data properly. Here's the code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>News Letter</h1>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="level" ></div>

    <div data-role="footer"></div>
        <h4>Powered by Handigital</h4>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
            $.ajax({
                    url:'NewsRecord.php',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success:function(output) {
                    for(var u=0;u < output.length;u++)
                    {
                    $('#level').append('<div>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:'+output[u].Title+'<br>Source  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:<a href='+output[u].links+'>'+output[u].Source+'</a><br>Category :'+output[u].Category+'</div><hr>');
                    }}
                    );
            });     
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the server from your localhost - that means, your files are not in the server and it is restricted due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). . Please take your files to the server and make ajax calls the same way you did locally. It will work.

If you intentionally want to make a cross domain request, use [JsonP Plugin](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp).

Or if you are targeted on modern devices or browsers, you can make cross domain requests using [Cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

[More info on JsonP](http://json-p.org/)

Hope it helps